# What is a simple way to make a basic website with graph database backend for newbie?

Tags: django, drupal, web-applications, content-management-system, neo4j

Graph database systems like ne04j seem to becoming very popular of late. I am a newbie user who is trying to set-up a website that needs to display some data which is best displayed using a graph database (essentially i will visualize this on the website).

I am designing this website using CMS Drupal but i am open to changing to other CMS or in worst case a web application framework like Django. Can anyone suggest me a basic template, website or extension to a CMS that enable graph databases or a good way to start learning web app development using graph databases for a noob ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is http://structr.org/, a CMS built on Neo4j and very Open and capable. Other bindings, you might take a look at [REST bindings](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/tutorials-rest.html) and [neo4j embedded bindings](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/languages.html) to get going.

Comment: This seems to be a very good project , i hope that version 1.0 is available soon

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you're curious about using Drupal to manage graphs, I'd recommend looking over these contributed modules:

- http://drupal.org/project/graphapi
- http://drupal.org/project/charts
- http://drupal.org/project/views_charts
- http://drupal.org/project/charts_graphs

Comment: Your answer does not make any sense. In this context graphs != charts.

Comment: Actually [graphapi](http://drupal.org/project/graphapi) is built to manage relations (hence proper graphs). Instead of charts, I would add other modules: - [relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation), which can manage x-nary relations, directed or undirecred, and can integrate with graphapi; - then one can visualize those relations with viz engines as [d3](http://drupal.org/project/d3). So the pipe I use is relation→graphapi→d3. And I must mention [neo4j_connector](https://www.drupal.org/project/neo4j_connector), a kind of neo4j overlay graph search engine on drupal (never tried).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for even more alternatives for charting in Drupal, then you may want to start from the [Comparison of charting module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985), which includes information and links about quite a lot of charting related modules in Drupal.

If you're aware of other modules not included in it, please update that docu if you can, or let me know about it.